# QT version update

Tags: qt

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and I've noticed that the system Qt libraries in /usr/lib/... have the version 4.8.1. Now this version of Qt is quite old and many important updates and bugfixes have been released meanwhile.

I'd like to ask whether there is a possibility to update these system libraries and if there is a tutorial how to do it - I'd need at least the version 4.8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the bugfixes are backported to your Qt release running on 12.04. So if you are running an up to date version, all fixes should be in -- even version number might not have changed. You can see details inside [ChangeLog](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/precise/libqt4-dev) from package information site. This might be confusing, but caused by packagaging and it's dependencies.

Comment: Thank you @frlan, this is a quite interesting information. So only to confirm, if I understand you correctly when I run the command  >qmake --version to obtain the Qt version, I obtain the version 4.8.1, but in fact, if I have a fully updated Ubuntu the Qt libraries, e.g. libQtNetwork.so are consistent with the latest (ubuntu updated) libraries (let's say 4.8.7 or whatever the latest release is)?

Comment: You are running a 4.8.1-something where something is including backported fixes which might not be equal with e.g. 4.8.4. But unless there is some real hackish things (e.g. working around a bug based on configure options) it should work

Comment: Thank you @frlan, I just tested my problem and it is like you said. My Qt still claims it has the version 4.8.1. but bug fixes from 4.8.4. that I needed to be applied were clearly applied. It is a bit unfortunate though that variables like QT_VERSION still returns 4.8.1. - it makes it hard to decide from within the code whether a patch is or isn't in place.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was refering to with work arounds. But its quiet commen. From time to time you could collect information from extra string and maybe having a white-list. But this will not work everywhere ...